# telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host - with docker installed

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, telnet, ubuntu-20.04

Before to run **sudo apt install -y docker-ce** I was able to run telnet without issues in my machine, but when I install that package I'm not able to run telnet successfully.

Before installing docker-ce

```
telnet 172.10.11.124 1521
Trying 172.10.11.124...
Connected to 172.10.11.124.
```

After installing docker-ce

```
telnet 172.10.11.124 1521
Trying 172.10.11.124...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

If I uninstall docker, Telnet runs without problems.

Can anyone help me how can I solve this problem with **docker-ce** installed?

Comment: Perhaps the docker network interface is mapped to that IP range (172.10). Try running `route` to look at the routing table, it'll show you if your request is trying to go through the docker interface.

Comment: Just to try, perform a telnet to another host, maybe public

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it's a network layer conflict with IPv4. You cannot connect to the mentioned IP because after you installed the Docker, it will create a virtual network.
To fix this issue, you must remove/change the Docker network. At first, inspect the networks by:

```
docker network ls
```

Then, after you'll get the list of networks, try to find the related network:

```
docker network inspect <network-id>
```

Finally, you can `rm` or reconfigure the Docker's virtual network as well.